# Null arguments bundle in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When passing arguments from the activity to the fragment, the arguments are lost.

Activity:

```
public class DatePickerFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_CRIME_DATE = "CRIME_DATE";
    private Date mCrimeDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        mCrimeDate = (Date) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_DATE);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    private Fragment createFragment(){
        return DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mCrimeDate);
    }
}
```

At this point, the fragment still has data in the bundle, checked by debugger.

```
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Fragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, container, false);
    }
}
```

But in this place the bundle is already empty:

```
mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
```

The layout of my application looks like this:

ListView Activity/Fragment -> ViewPager Activity/Fragment -> DatePicker Activity/Fragment

Comment: have you checked is Date in activity that you passing to Fragment is not null?

Comment: Because Intent is already present in Activity, no need to pass using setArguments. just call `mDate = (Date) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_DATE);`

Comment: mCrimeDate = (Date) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_DATE); is null

Comment: @AntonisRadz Of course. The fragment instance in activity has the correct bundle.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK 
I'll try your solution tomorrow, thanks. Sounds like something working. But it's still interesting why the bundle is null in fragment.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Move your message to the answers so that I can mark it as the correct answer.